# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'overlay'

Tags: javascript

Why do I get this error from my overlay jquery code?

This is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // if the function argument is given to overlay,
    // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
    $("a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'darkred',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

    });
});
```

This code is the overlay like this: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html

Halp?

ps. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is not enough code to demonstrate you're doing this correctly. According to the link you gave there are multiple steps to set up the overlay. We don't know if you set it up correctly, could you give us more of the page and how you set it up?

Comment: This work perfectly in html but when i try to include this plugin into wordpress theme doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the `overlay` plugin before jQuery will see it as part of the object; see below.
*Note: the plugin must come after the jQuery script*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I must load the `overlay.js` plugin before `jquery.js`?

Comment: I use wordpress.. and the jQuery script is in <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  ?> and i load the overlay plugin (the code above) after the jQuery script.

Comment: humanbeing, no, you need to load the overlay plugin after the jquery plugin.  The error you're getting is because the browser doesn't see `overlay` as part of your jquery object (either you tried to load the plugin before jquery, or you didn't load the plugin at all) -- the plugin is in the second script tag (jquery.tools.min.js).

Comment: now i try to include the jquery.tools.min.js in wordpress by following this guide http://www.themightymo.com/2011/02/01/how-to-include-jquery-tools-tooltips-in-wordpress-theme/ but it doesn't work, and i get this error: jquery.tool.min.js:69 Uncaught Could not find Overlay: nofollow

Answer (score 4):

"Could not find Overlay: nofollow" is caused by using a non-specific css selector to find the links you want to attach your overlay to.

Including the javascript properly was the correct answer to the initial question... I came to this page based on the Overlay: nofollow issue in a comment.... since this is the first thing I found and didn't find an answer I wanted to comment here since I found it is caused by the css selector finding other uses of .. and there isn't a nofollow overlay...

assuming 'overlay' is the id of your div as in the following:

```
<!-- overlayed element -->
<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
   < !-- the external content is loaded inside this tag -- >
   <div class="contentWrap"></div>

</div>
```

you should be doing something like:

```
 $("a[rel=#overlay]").overlay(
```

instead of:

```
 $("a[rel]").overlay(
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem and found a really strange solution.
I just included jquery.tools **before** jquery.ui in this way:

```
 <script src='js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 <script src='js/jquery.tools.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 <script src='js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

That's all. No idea why it works now but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the overlay script src in  your page?

Comment: yes.. as <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/overlay.js"></script>

Comment: see my comment below your question.