# How to use the .click function with overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the `.click` function with the overlay from jQuery tools, but it is not working.

**HTML:**

```
<p id="click">Clikc here:</p>
<div class="pop">
  <div>
    <p>some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery function:**

```
 $( "#click" ).click(function(){
 $( ".pop" ).overlay({
     top: 10,
     mask: {color:'#595959',loadSpeed: 1000,opacity: 0.5},
     closeOnClick: false,
     api: true
 });
```

I have already added the `(document).ready` at the top. I want the overlay to pop up when the user clicks the text.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have problems when i am to add in the script

Comment: Where is the .terms class from?

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: yes and there is no errors. I edited the .terms class and implemented .pop

Comment: Which overlay plugin are you using?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with same id `#click` ??

Comment: no I do not. Only one

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the code to 2 operations, 1. Define the overlay, 2. programarically launch the overlay. See [this demo](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/trigger.htm)

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $(".pop").overlay().load();
    });

    $(".pop").overlay({
        top: 10,
        mask: {
            color: '#595959',
            loadSpeed: 1000,
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        closeOnClick: false,
        api: true
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5w9B7/)

Comment: @user3052886 did you try the fiddle and the demo from jQuery tools

Comment: the fiddle is perfect that is how I want it, and I did try the demo from jQuery tools. When I implement the code nothing happens when I click the text

Comment: I even trired adding event.preventDefault under the .click function

Comment: @user3052886 may be something else is blocking the event to happen, Debug in your console and check whether any error fires out.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'overlay' place.js:36
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
2
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'overlay'

Comment: sorry I didn't refresh. It now says: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'overlay' place.js:36
(anonymous function) place.js:36
c jquery.js:4
p.fireWith jquery.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery.js:4
q

Comment: @user3052886 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547138/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-overlay

Comment: you have not included the jQuery Tools plugin in your page

Comment: I did include the jquery tools plugin: <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

Comment: I put it after the jquery pluggin and I get more errors on the counsel

Comment: Try `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>`

Comment: use `http://` before your src url. like `http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js`

Comment: I added the script type and still nothing, does any one want to view my screen?

Comment: @user3052886 not the script type. Have you tried using `http://` before `src` url?

Comment: @user3052886 can you share a simplified version of your file

Comment: @user3052886 include a screenshot of your web console

Comment: @Arun P Johny how? and I will do that Prasanth K C

Comment: @user3052886 copy the source your questin

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. The problem is in the jQuery tools version 1.2.5, it seems as if the overlay is not a method and also in the 1.2.6. What I had to do is use the version 1.2.7 and it worked. I loaded it right after my original jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js""></script>
```